# Lenovo Legion 5P Screen Brightness stuck at max

Tags: lenovo, laptop, brightness, backlight

I just got a new Lenovo 5p (15IMH05H) and got xubuntu on it

But the screen is stuck at max brightness and it just won't turn down
The controls works, it sets the values in /sys/class/backlight/ and setting those by hand doesn't help

In grub I tried

- setting acpi_osi to `blank` and to `linux`
- setting acpi_backlight to `video` `vendor` and `native`

Set values be hand with echo and tee , tried every combination of of the NVIDIA Prime video setting (discrete, on-demand, and intel)

I'm at my wit's end, and my retinas too. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: also tried
`Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` in the xorg configs, with and without a `;`

No dice

Comment: I keep being asked for this elsewhere, so:
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
`intel_backlight`